# Insert cursor into new collection Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So, i have two collections, Cycles and Alarms and I aggregated them.

```
cursor = db.cycles.aggregate([{

    '$lookup': {

        'from': 'Alarms',
        'localField': 'CycleTime',
        'foreignField': 'CycleTIme',
        'as': 'joined'
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'ArticleID':'$ArticleID',
        'InjectionTime [s]': '$InjectionTime [s]',
        'PauseTime [s]': '$PauseTime [s]',
        'CycleTime': '$CycleTime',
        'Cycle [s]': '$Cycle [s]',
        'AlarmExplanation': '$joined.AlarmExplanation',
        'AlarmTime': '$joined.AlarmTime',


    }
}])
```

But now, I would like to save that cursor as a new, 'Joined' collection, so I could do more operations with it.

I can't find anything for pymongo, only found .toArray() for mongodb?

Comment: you should store the result of your query in a new collection (use **`$out`** for this) and jsut call `db.collection.find()` to get a cursor

Comment: @felix Thanks, it works